# Javascript Datepicker calendário exibindo ano errado

Tags: javascript, datepicker, django-templates

Estou trabalhando com Django e utilizando um datepicker para selecionar a data em um campo de um formulário:

```
<h3>Data de recebimento</h3>
        {{ form.creation_date }}


<script>
    $(function () {
        $("#id_creation_date").datepicker({
            format:'dd/mm/yyyy',
        });
    });
</script>
```

No formulário de criação, ao clicar aparece o calendário no mês atual e a data é salva corretamente, porém quando vou editar um formulário, ao clicar no campo de data o calendário exibe o ano de 1911:

[image: Imagem do calendário exibindo o ano de 1911]

É possível definir o mês padrão para ser exibido? O estranho é que quando o campo está vazio isso já é feito.

Obs: no Django os ids são gerados automaticamente com o nome do campo com "id_" na frente, por isso o campo `creation_date`é referenciado como `id_creation_date`e isso aparentemente não tem a ver com o problema.

```
 <!-- Datepicker -->
   <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.css" integrity="sha256-b88RdwbRJEzRx95nCuuva+hO5ExvXXnpX+78h8DjyOE=" crossorigin="anonymous" />
   <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datepicker/0.6.5/datepicker.min.js" integrity="sha256-/7FLTdzP6CfC1VBAj/rsp3Rinuuu9leMRGd354hvk0k=" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

Comment: Antes de apresentar na view, tens de converter a data vinda do servidor no formato desejado.

Comment: tenho que converter a data que foi salva no formulário de criação pra que o datepicker exiba o mês correto?

Comment: Sim, podes fazê-lo diretamente com a query na base de dados ou no servidor antes de retornar a data para o cliente.